# Stored Procedure not giving the correct results in MVC Project

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

The SP that I use works as it should in SQL Management studio but this is the only query that gets me the wrong results in my project.

The SP query is:

```
SELECT DISTINCT Vehicle_Model_Range.ModelRange_ID, Users.MapLat, 
Users.MapLong, Users.User_ID, Users.Status_ID, Vehicle_Details.Approved, 
Vehicle_Details.Vehicle_Type
FROM            
                     Users INNER JOIN
                     Vehicle_Details ON Users.User_ID = 
                     Vehicle_Details.User_ID INNER JOIN
                     Vehicle_Make ON Vehicle_Details.Make_ID = 
                     Vehicle_Make.Make_ID INNER JOIN
                     Vehicle_Model ON Vehicle_Details.Model_ID = 
                     Vehicle_Model.Model_ID INNER JOIN
                     Vehicle_Model_Range ON Vehicle_Model.ModelRange_Id = 
                     Vehicle_Model_Range.ModelRange_ID

WHERE       
(Vehicle_Details.Approved = 1)
AND (Users.Status_ID = 1)
AND (Vehicle_Details.Vehicle_Type = 'V')
AND (Users.MapLat IS NOT NULL)
AND (Users.MapLong IS NOT NULL)
AND (Vehicle_Model_Range.ModelRange_ID IS NOT NULL)
```

Here's the code in VS that uses it:

```
   public ActionResult Search(string Location)
    {
        GoogleMapEntities GE = new GoogleMapEntities();

        var GetVeh = db.GetMapSearch().Where(x => 
        (x.ModelRange_ID.ToString().StartsWith(Location)) && (x.Vehicle_Type 
        == "V") && (x.Status_ID == 1) && (x.Approved == true)).ToList();

        return Json(GetVeh, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
    }
```

Basically, what happens is that it plots all the points onto the map and does not follow the where statement that says that it should only plot for the following where conditions:

```
WHERE       

(Vehicle_Details.Approved = 1)
AND (Users.Status_ID = 1)
AND (Vehicle_Details.Vehicle_Type = 'V')
AND (Users.MapLat IS NOT NULL)
AND (Users.MapLong IS NOT NULL)
AND (Vehicle_Model_Range.ModelRange_ID IS NOT NULL)
```

I have updated the model a few times and the SP does not work.

EDIT:

I have just added those where conditions to the linq query but still does not work. Any ideas?

EDIT: Full Stored Proc

```
USE [X_DB]
GO
/****** Object:  StoredProcedure [dbo].[sp_App_MapSearch]    Script Date: 
2017/06/26 9:16:10 AM ******/
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO

ALTER PROC [dbo].[sp_App_MapSearch]

AS 
BEGIN

SELECT DISTINCT Vehicle_Model_Range.ModelRange_ID, Users.MapLat, 
Users.MapLong, Users.User_ID, Users.Status_ID, Vehicle_Details.Approved, 
Vehicle_Details.Vehicle_Type
FROM            Users INNER JOIN
                Vehicle_Details ON Users.User_ID = 
                Vehicle_Details.User_ID INNER JOIN
                Vehicle_Make ON Vehicle_Details.Make_ID = 
                Vehicle_Make.Make_ID INNER JOIN
                Vehicle_Model ON Vehicle_Details.Model_ID = 
                Vehicle_Model.Model_ID INNER JOIN
                Vehicle_Model_Range ON Vehicle_Model.ModelRange_Id = 
                Vehicle_Model_Range.ModelRange_ID
WHERE       
(Vehicle_Details.Approved = 1)
AND (Users.Status_ID = 1)
AND (Vehicle_Details.Vehicle_Type = 'V')
AND (Users.MapLat IS NOT NULL)
AND (Users.MapLong IS NOT NULL)
AND (Vehicle_Model_Range.ModelRange_ID IS NOT NULL)

END
```

Comment: What does the method `db.DropDownModelRange()` look like?

Comment: That' the SP query posted above

Comment: I've changed the code above as the other one was the incorrect code for the search, GetMapSearch is now the query above.

Comment: What does `db.GetMapSearch()` look like? And don't say it is the stored procedure above, because the SP is in SQL, and the method is in C#. How does C# call the query. And can you you should the full stored procedure from the `CREATE PROC` to the `END`.

Comment: Added to original post. It gets the query in the MVC model just like it does for the others, it gets the results for all the others but for this one it's just not doing there where statements properly so therefore it is giving the incorrect result. In the Model, the SP exists there and the Function Import Name is "GetMapSearch" and that is called in the C# code.

Comment: You're saying the query is executing but without the WHERE clause. SQL Server wouldn't drop a WHERE clause. IF you have created a stored proc in the DB, and IF you are just calling that proc from GetMapSearch, all should work as expected. Are you sure the stored proc is being executed against the correct database, or that you aren't mapping to another version of the stored proc without the WHERE clause?

Comment: What do you mean "function import name is GetMapSearch". What are you using to access the database? EF, LINQ to SQL, NHibernate, plain ADO.NET? (Ttat's why I wanted to see the method, I don't know what `db` is or how it works)

Comment: The proc is being called otherwise the other functions will not work. Not to be rude, but this is an MVC project and maybe that's why there's confusion ?  If you work with MVC you should know about the Function Import Name. It is LINQ in C# and by looking at the code you should be able to understand what is happening if you do work with MVC. Like I have said, I am not trying to be rude, I just don't understand why the where statement is not working as it should but the rest of the procedure does and if it did not, I wouldn't get any result at all.

Comment: The Function Name is what you call the proc once you've imported it into the model. For that proc, I called it GetMapSearch.